# eclipselink: NullPointerException on QueryImpl.unwrap()

Tags: spring, eclipselink, querydsl

I am working on the upgrade of a very old application. And if you wonder why we do not simply restart from zero, the application is very big and it is something
not possible :(

So I am in the process of migrating from:

- spring 4 to **spring 5.3.27**
- mysema to **querydsl 4**
- jpa 1 to **spring-data-jpa 2.7.11**

As additional information we do not use **hibernate** but **eclipselink 2.6.4**

I think I am almost done but I am facing an issue when processing the following request

```
@Query("select d from Dossier d,  d.allotements a where a.lot = :lot order by d.id desc")
public List<Dossier> getDossiersPourUnLot(@Param("lot") Lot lot);
```

and I am having the following error.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.unwrap(QueryImpl.java:1155)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    net.bull.javamelody.JpaWrapper$QueryHandler.invoke(JpaWrapper.java:170)
    net.bull.javamelody.JdbcWrapper$DelegatingInvocationHandler.invoke(JdbcWrapper.java:300)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy128.unwrap(Unknown Source)
    org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.QueryParameterSetter$BindableQuery.<init>(QueryParameterSetter.java:316)
    org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.QueryParameterSetter$QueryMetadata.withQuery(QueryParameterSetter.java:257)
    org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinder.bind(ParameterBinder.java:74)
    org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinder.bindAndPrepare(ParameterBinder.java:96)
    org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractStringBasedJpaQuery.doCreateQuery(AbstractStringBasedJpaQuery.java:101)
    org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.createQuery(AbstractJpaQuery.java:233)
    org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:128)
    org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:90)
    org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:156)
    org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:144)
    org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137)
    org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121)
    org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:160)
    org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:139)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:81)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:145)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:220)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy144.getDossiersPourUnLot(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:220)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy144.getDossiersPourUnLot(Unknown Source)
    com.iselection.portail.service.dossier.DossierEntityService.getDossiersPourUnLot(DossierEntityService.java:1366)
```

I guess the error comes because of the line `org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.QueryParameterSetter$BindableQuery.<init>(QueryParameterSetter.java:316)`
which does `this.unwrapped = Proxy.isProxyClass(query.getClass()) ? query.unwrap(null) : query;`
But I have no idea why it happens nor what I should check.

Does anyone have any idea what I can do ?

Thanks in advance for any idea or explanation :)

Comment: my bad, this was a side effet of our custom jpaVendorAdapter :/

Comment: That is still odd code, as it shouldn't be passing in null to unwrap. the persistence Query class should throw a PersistenceException since it cannot return null, or the latest Spring code (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/main/spring-data-jpa/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/query/QueryParameterSetter.java ) would get an NPE anyway as it calls .getClass() on what should be a null value returned. Glad you found the issue as the code here isn't built for JPA but Springs own JPA implementation classes.